# OrientDB Gremlin - g.getVertices to do a fulltext search/match on a property

Tags: full-text-search, orientdb, gremlin, orientdb-2.1

I'm trying to find out how can I do a LIKE query in gremlin using the getVertices or similar method, which would hit the indexes. I'm using OrientDB 2.1.11 and Gremlin.

This works, but does an exact match:
    `g.getVertices('city_state.city','VANCOUVER')`

What I need to do is something like below (doesn't work though):
    `g.getVertices('city_state.city','VANC%')`

Would be awesome if I can use the LUCENE index, if its supported.

Comment: is it correct: ----->    
g.getVerticesOfClass('city_state')._().filter{it.getProperty('city').matches('VAN.*')}

Answer (score 0):

You could try this query:

```
g.V.has('@class','city_state').filter{it.city.matches('VA‌​N.*')}
```

or this (similar to yours):

```
g.V.has('@class','city_state').filter{it.getProperty('city').matches('VA‌​N.*')}
```

Comment: ^ returns in 7+ secs consistently, while -> g.getVerticesOfClass('city_state')._().filter{it.city.matches('VAN.*')}   returns in 0.43 seconds. Count of V = 1,170,585 records, while city_state class has 15,965 records. I don't think its hitting indexes (I have a dictionary index and a fulltext index created on the city field).